# FreeMarker: Enumeration of Root

Tags: freemarker

I am looking to enumerate the root object in FTL (freeMarker template language).  for all hash arrays, and all sequence arrays, and all standard key value objects.

I need output in JSON format.
I have found the posted code for JSON enumeration:
http://ericbrandel.com/2013/03/28/freemarker-container-to-json/

```
<#macro objectToJsonMacro object> 
<@compress single_line=true> 
    <#if object?is_hash || object?is_hash_ex> 
    <#assign first="true"> 
    { 
    <#list object?keys as key> 
        <#if first="false">,</#if> 
        <#assign value><@objectToJsonMacro object=object<key> /></#assign> 
        "${key}" : ${value?trim} 
        <#assign first="false"> 
    </#list> 
    } 
    <#elseif object?is_enumerable> 
    <#assign first="true"> 
    [ 
    <#list object as item> 
        <#if first="false">,</#if> 
        <#assign value><@objectToJsonMacro object=item /></#assign> 
        ${value?trim} 
        <#assign first="false"> 
    </#list> 
    ] 
    <#else> 
    "${object?trim}" 
    </#if> 
</@compress> 
</#macro>
```

But the code does NOT WORK (throws an error) in the latest edition of FreeMarker.

I would appreciate any help that anyone can provide.  Also, I don't see a way to "get" the root object.

Thanks,
Dan Linstedt

Comment: And what error does it throw?

Comment: The data-model (I suppose that's what you mean by root object) is accessible as `.data_model` (see http://freemarker.org/docs/ref_specvar.html).

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by adding a public method to my root object which JSON encodes itself. I used [Gson](https://github.com/google/gson/blob/master/UserGuide.md) to marshal the object.

```java
/**
 * @return JSON serialized version of this object.
 */
public String toJson()
{
    GsonBuilder gsonBuilder = new GsonBuilder();
    //gsonBuilder.setPrettyPrinting();
    //gsonBuilder.disableHtmlEscaping();
    // .. and whatever else you need Gson to do
    return gsonBuilder.create().toJson(this);
}
```

I didn't need it in FreeMarker, but you could access it like:

```
${toJson()}
```